# JPA EclipseLink Oracle11 - Takes loong time

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, oracle11g, query-optimization, jpql

I am working on a Java EE 7 EAR application made up of Maven modules.  It makes database calls to an Oracle 11 database on another server on the LAN.  I'm deploying to Glassfish 4.0.1-b03 running on Ubuntu 12.04.  I've just now pulled down the latest OJDBC6.jar from Oracle.  As per http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/gbxjh.html I put the ojdbc6.jar in `domain1/lib/ext`.

Using SQLDeveloper and querying the database with what is pretty-much the same query takes 10 miliseconds.  The same query through the JPA/JPQL takes 0.5 to 3 minutes depending on the configuration and I'm trying to get this down to something more reasonable.

The query returns 40 rows so pagination won't help.

I use Wireshark to monitor the data being returned and the time taken is all on the database.  The problem must lie in the query being sent.

I turned on logging with the following and I'm showing what I believe is the query EclipseLink is sending to the DB:

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINEST" />
```

### Config 1

persistence.xml contains:

```
<property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Oracle"/>
```

Query in log:

```
SELECT ALERT_P, CNT, COLOUR, DFROMUIDCNT, FROMUIDCNT, IS_PRIORITYWORD, IS_STOPWORD, N, NIJ, NRTCNT, PJ, RTCCNT, RTCNT, TIME_STAMP, STEM, TWEETS FROM ALL_ALERTS WHERE (TIME_STAMP BETWEEN ? AND ?) ORDER BY TIME_STAMP, STEM
```

Time taken 25 seconds

### Config 2

Change persistence.xml to contain:

```
<property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Oracle11"/>
```

There is an exception:

```
 org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: HINT
                                    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:765)
                                    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
                                    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
                                    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
                                    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
                                    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$2.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:451)
                                    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
                                    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.iterateInitializedPUsAtApplicationPrepare(JPADeployer.java:492)
                                    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:395)
                                    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
                                    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:484)
                                    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
                                    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
                                    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
                                    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
                                    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                                    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
                                    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
                                    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
                                    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
                                    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                                    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
                                    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
                                    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
                                    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
                                    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
                                    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
                                    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
                                    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
                                    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
                                    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:496)
                                    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:175)
                                    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
                                    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
                                    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:187)
                                    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
                                    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
                                    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
                                    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
                                    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
                                    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
                                    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:837)
                                    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
                                    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
                                    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
                                    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
                                    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
                                    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

According to http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Oracle one should use Oracle11.  I don't know why I'm getting this exception.  **Any thoughts on this problem?**

### Config 3

Remove `eclipselink.target-database` from persistence.xml.

Query is:

```
SELECT ALERT_P, CNT, COLOUR, DFROMUIDCNT, FROMUIDCNT, IS_PRIORITYWORD, IS_STOPWORD, N, NIJ, NRTCNT, PJ, RTCCNT, RTCNT, TIME_STAMP, STEM, TWEETS FROM ALL_ALERTS WHERE (TIME_STAMP BETWEEN ? AND ?) ORDER BY TIME_STAMP, STEM
```

Oh, its the same as above so obviously this is not what is being sent to Oracle.

Time taken: 2.5 minutes.

So the EclipseLink property is helping but perhaps the value of "Oracle11" would work better if I can get that going.

### Config 4

Same as **Config 3** excepting I removed the `ORDER BY TIMESTAMP, STEM`.

Time taken: 1.5 minutes.

### Config 5

Same as **Config 1** excepting I removed the `ORDER BY TIMESTAMP, STEM`.

Time taken: 25 seconds.

### Config 6

I restored the `ORDER BY` and moved the `ojdbc6.jar` from `lib/ext` to `lib/`.

Time taken: 26 seconds.

### Config 7

Same as **Config 6** but changed the `eclipselink.target-database` to `Oracle11` and this time the error is:

```
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/sql/TIMESTAMP
```

Verifying the wiki page as correct that the jar needs to be in `ext` to pick up the Oracle-specific extensions.

It seems to me the problem is that the query being sent to Oracle isn't optimized for it.

Can anyone tell me:

1. What that exception when using "Oracle11" is (when the jar is in `ext/`)?
2. Is there any other way the query can be optimized for Oracle?

Next I'm going to try a `@NamedNativeQuery` to see if I can use the same query used in.  SQLDeveloper.  Though the query isn't complex so I can't see this will improve on what JPA can do.  That query is:

```
select * from all_alerts t1 WHERE t1.time_stamp between to_date('2013-01-22 16:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and to_date('2013-01-22 16:05:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ORDER BY t1.time_stamp, t1.stem;
```

Actually what I'll try first is to make sure the dates I'm sending in my JPQL queries are of the same format.

Any comments or feedback appreciated.

### Update

Now for something interesting I forgot to add before.  The following `@NamedQuery` runs in the expected time (0.086 secs for one query).

```
        @NamedQuery(name = "AllAlert.findLatestAlerts", query = "SELECT a FROM AllAlert a WHERE a.id.timeStamp in"
            + " (SELECT MAX(a.id.timeStamp) from AllAlert AS a) ORDER BY a.id.stem"),
```

This seems more complex to me.

Comment: Nope can only pass a `java.util.Date` so what happens with that (the format) is being left to the mercy of JPA.

Comment: A native query like the above got the time down to 0.099 seconds.  Pretty happy about that but would like to know why EclipseLink doesn't achieve this also.

Comment: For the "NoSuchFieldError: HINT" problem - provide the full stack trace so that the internal cause can be tracked down in the code

Comment: Updated with full exception stack trace.

Comment: No answers?  Doesn't it seem weird that a more complex JPQL query runs in the expected time whereas what I consider to be a simpler query takes longer?  Noone has any thoughts about this???